# No response from web server in Docker container from host

Tags: docker, tcp

I am running a web server (Java Spring boot application) inside a Docker container on port 8080, which is exposed to interface 127.0.0.1 also on port 8080.

`docker ps` shows that the port is exposed:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
a055dd0dbbfe        image               "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"T…"   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp   my-app_1
```

`netstat -an` in the host shows the port is actually listening:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35900         127.0.0.1:8080          FIN_WAIT2
tcp      142      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:35900         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      1 172.18.0.1:36626        172.18.0.3:8080         SYN_SENT
```

If I try to access the server from the Docker host

```
wget 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I can see that the connection is established, the HTTP request is sent, but no response is received. The connection is closed by peer after a time. This behavior is reflected in `tcpdump` as well:

```
21:01:14.174522 IP localhost.35872 > localhost.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 441189964, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 342973 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:01:14.174546 IP localhost.http-alt > localhost.35872: Flags [S.], seq 3411015394, ack 441189965, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 342973 ecr 342973,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:01:14.174570 IP localhost.35872 > localhost.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 342973 ecr 342973], length 0
21:01:14.176050 IP localhost.35872 > localhost.http-alt: Flags [P.], seq 1:142, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 342973 ecr 342973], length 141: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
21:01:14.176068 IP localhost.http-alt > localhost.35872: Flags [.], ack 142, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 342973 ecr 342973], length 0
21:03:21.418268 IP localhost.http-alt > localhost.35872: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 142, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 374784 ecr 342973], length 0
```

The webserver in the container works. Spring Boot server listens to all interfaces (`lo` and `eth0`):

```
Application 'app' is running! Access URLs:
Local:          http://127.0.0.1:8080
External:       http://172.18.0.3:8080
```

and I can successfully `wget` from inside the container:

`docker exec <container> wget localhost:8080`:

```
Connecting to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
index.html           100% |*******************************| 12560   0:00:00 ETA
```

Docker version is `18.09.2` for client and engine.

OS is Ubuntu, `uname -a`:

```
Linux srv02 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have no idea what could be wrong?

Comment: In your container, is the SpringBoot app listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 or localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)? Can you put the SpringBoot log from the start up which shows the binging of the port?

Comment: You said "If I try to access the server from outside" and then you show a command using `localhost` - by outside, you mean a different machine? Or you mean "outside the container from the host running the container?"

What is localhost mapped to? Did you try 127.0.0.1:8080?

Comment: Good points! Spring Boot listens to both interfaces `lo` and `eth0` on port 8080. Changed "from outside" to "from the Docker host". `localhost` is mapped to 127.0.0.1, I also tried without DNS.

Comment: Your container is trying to contact something on 172.18.0.3, which is not responding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate, though? Why should my container try to contact something? I am trying to contact an app in the container from the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found the problem it's obvious. There was an iptables filter configured by the provider that dropped all "output" packets to unknown ports such as 8080.